# Security Patch SUPEE-10888 - Possible issues?

Tags: magento-1, patches, security, supee-10888

SUPEE-10888 is a new security patch for Magento 1 which addresses 12 security issues.

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10888

> SUPEE-10888, Magento Commerce 1.14.3.10 and Open Source 1.9.3.10 contain multiple security enhancements that help close cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and other vulnerabilities.

The patch can be found at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2243

What common issues do you have to watch out for when applying this patch?

Comment: Cannot send password via email to customers who register during checkout

Comment: @Haim in these StackExchange questions about patch issue it is common practise to create an "Answer" where you explain on which Magento version with which patch  file you experience a certain problem.

Comment: @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost Understood. That's not really a patch issue, just something that Magento themselves mention on the release of the patch

Answer (score 6):

Below files have been changed/created after the patch is applied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml 
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml 
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.6.1.1-1.6.2.0.6.1.2.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php 
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php 
app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml 
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html 
app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html 
downloader/Maged/Controller.php downloader/Maged/Controller.php
skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

In the original v1 patches with `2018-09-18` in the filename:

```
File skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg: git binary diffs are not supported.
```

Magento did silently fix this issue by releasing new patch files. Still `v1` but with `2018-09-19` in the filename.

Comment: My solution is to skip this change by removing the line starting with
`diff --git skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg` and all following lines from the patch file

Comment: I think Magento will come with a V2 version for this patch with this issue fixed in the next couple of days...

Comment: pretty sure the patches have been updated, but keeping the number as v1? redownload and check.

Comment: @LukeRodgers They did! How sneaky! I will edit this issue.

Comment: 1.7.02 CE version of the patch is still not updated.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with patch `PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.0.1_v1-2018-09-18-02-54-39.sh` on vanilla Magento 1.8.1.0, with all previous patches installed:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 1019
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
|index b1ec5eb0460..ca3e8b32474 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
--------------------------
```

Indeed the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml` does not exist in 1.8.1.0 so I removed this change from the patch file.

I did not succeeded in doing this with the updated, `2018-09-19` version of the patch. Only succeeded with file `PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.8.1.0_v1-2018-09-18-02-54-39` after also removing the `thumbnail.jpg` change like explained in my comment on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/242823/13642

Comment: Do you think it makes sense for them to release v2 version? and how did the patch install on 1.7.0.2 ?

Comment: This is because you are trying to patch 1.8.1.0 using the patch for 1.9.0.1. Look carefully at the name of the patch you are using "PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.0.1_...."    - "...CE_v1.9.0.1..."

Comment: @AndreyBorgoyakov I am using the right patch. The patches are named the after the highest version they are compatible with. You can check on https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2243. The path file I am using is `SUPEE-10888 for CE 1.8.1.0-1.9.0.1 (0.06 MB)`

Comment: @Icon after fixing https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/242823/13642 the patch installed well on 1.7.0.2. This is the order of the patches we installed on 1.7.0.2: 
SUPEE-2677 SUPEE-2629 SUPEE-1049 SUPEE-1868-1-12-0-2 SUPEE-4334-v1.11.1.0 SUPEE-5345 SUPEE-5994 SUPEE-6237 SUPEE-6285 SUPEE-6482 SUPEE-6788 SUPEE-7405-CE-1-7-0-2 SUPEE-7405 SUPEE-7616 SUPEE-8167 SUPEE-8788 SUPEE-8967 SUPEE-9652 PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v2 SUPEE-10336_v1.13.0.2 SUPEE-10266-CE-1.7.0.2 SUPEE-10415-ce-1.7.0.2 SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.7.0.2 SUPEE-10752_CE_v1.7.0.2 SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.7.0.2

Comment: I looked over the patch description, haven't found any Critital improvements as we've seen in other patches. No particular urgency to install, what do you think?

Comment: I would install all patches, because next patches will depend on previous ones.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using custom theme and your theme overrides any of below file then you need to add changes manually in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
```

for example if you have added

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
```

in your theme , then you have to do changes manually in

```
app/design/frontend/[YourPackge]/[YourTheme]/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
```

**For example** 
Find these line

```
$attributes['option_label']
```

and replace with below

```
$this->escapeHtml($attributes['option_label']);
```

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243531/142, you need to check all your custom frontend template files and include the changes from the patch there manually.

Besides of that, you need to check your `account_password_reset_confirmation.html` mail template. Depending on your store, either under `app/locale/[LANG]/template/email/` or in the backend under System > Transactional Emails for all languages. In all respective templates, you need to change `_query_id=$customer.id` to `_query_id=$customer.rp_customer_id`. The change has been implemented in a backwards-compatible manner, but if you want to include all security improvements, you should not miss this change.

Answer (score 1):

Today Morning I have applied the patch. The major files are in Magento backend.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5.1.2-1.6.2.0.5.1.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php
app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html
downloader/Maged/Controller.php
skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

## **Escapehtml added files**

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
```

**In Magento commerce added files other than the above files:**

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftRegistry/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftRegistry/Model/Attribute/Processor.php
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/cms/hierarchy/pagination.phtml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/cms/hierarchy/pagination.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/rma/return/view.phtml
```

I do not face any issue till now.

Answer (score 1):

Password reset form no longer works after installing the patch on CE 1.7.0.2 with all previous patches installed.

(PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.7.0.2_v1-2018-09-18-03-00-22.sh)

EDIT:

Issue no longer occures after reverting patch from September 18 (v1) and applying the updated patch from September 19 (v1) + cache refresh and clearing magento cache.

(PATCH_SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.7.0.2_v1-2018-09-19-03-01-22.sh)

Answer (score 1):

**In Magento EE 1.13.1.0**

Patch is looking for wrong file (community file, I believe).

Had to delete these lines from patch file and apply. It applied successfully.

**Have notified Magento core team, yet to receive feedback.**

```
diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
index b3e997f59f3..f34c2bba6a2 100644
--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@
     <?php $attributes = $this->getSelectionAttributes($_item) ?>
     <?php if ($_prevOptionId != $attributes['option_id']): ?>
     <tr class="bundle label<?php if($_item->getLastRow()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
-        <td><div class="option-label"><?php echo $attributes['option_label'] ?></div></td>
+        <td><div class="option-label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($attributes['option_label']); ?></div></td>
         <td data-rwd-label="SKU" class="lin-hide">&nbsp;</td>
         <td data-rwd-label="Price" class="lin-hide">&nbsp;</td>
         <td data-rwd-label="Qty" class="lin-hide">&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Did you ever hear back about this?

Comment: Yes, they sent me another patch in the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Robb for the clue.

SUPEE-10752 was needed to be applied. I also applied, the PHP 7.2 compatibility patch and removed the Inchoo_PHP7 compatibility patch before installing SUPEE-10888. Worked without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Magento CE 1.6.2.0

Following error once patch is applied when trying to reset customer account password on the frontend.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1536.

Turns out, the patch hadn't ran the SQL upgrade script (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.0.1.2-1.6.1.0.1.3.php) which created a new attribute called rp_customer_id.

Check that you've cleared Magento Cache, but more importantly if you have varnish cache enabled, clear it. After I disabled all of the cache, and cleaned varnish cache, the SQL script created the new attribute in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Found a little typo in the patch for 1.14.2.0 to 1.14.2.4

In the file `app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml`, it mistakenly makes the following change:

`<dt><?php echo $this->escspeHtml($this->getLinksTitle()); ?></dt>`

instead of

`<dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getLinksTitle()); ?></dt>`

Here's the diff for reference:

`diff --git app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
index 6ed3cd9bfd4..f8b1573605a 100644
--- app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
         <!-- downloadable -->
         <?php if ($links = $this->getLinks()): ?>
             <dl class="item-options">
-                <dt><?php echo $this->getLinksTitle() ?></dt>
+                <dt><?php echo $this->escspeHtml($this->getLinksTitle()); ?></dt>
                 <?php foreach ($links->getPurchasedItems() as $link): ?>
                     <dd><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($link->getLinkTitle()); ?></dd>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Very nice find!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo inside `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml` at `<crate_admin_user_notification translate="label comment">` it should be `<create_admin_user_notification translate="label comment">` but it's non breaking because the usages is also spelled wrong at `if(Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('admin/security/crate_admin_user_notification')`

Answer (score 0):

Currently failing here on Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 57.
```

A visual check of the source files confirms that the relevant code isn't there.

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #3 FAILED at 845.
```

...

```
can't find file to patch at input line 600
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
```

As indicated, there's no such file.

```
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 209.
```

Comment: This turned out to be because SUPEE-10752 had not been applied previously.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI for EE users, since this patch requires **SUPEE-10752** you might encounter some sessions being randomly dropped or your checkout redirects to the homepage instead of the success page.

We went to the usual process of applying the following patches in this order:

1. SUPEE-10570v2 (PATCH_SUPEE-10570_EE_v1.14.2.4_v2-2018-03-22-10-57-00.sh)
2. SUPEE-10752 (PATCH_SUPEE-10752_EE_v1.14.2.4_v1-2018-06-25-09-53-38.sh)
3. SUPEE-10888 (PATCH_SUPEE-10888_EE_v1.14.2.4_v1-2018-09-19-03-07-06.sh)

However, the patch **SUPEE-10752** for EE contains the following changes:
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

```
+    const VALIDATOR_PASSWORD_CREATE_TIMESTAMP   = 'password_create_timestamp';


+    /**
+     * Use password creation timestamp in validator key
+     *
+     * @return bool
+     */
+    public function useValidateSessionPasswordTimestamp()
+    {
+        return true;
+    }


+        if ($this->useValidateSessionPasswordTimestamp()
+            && isset($validatorData[self::VALIDATOR_PASSWORD_CREATE_TIMESTAMP])
+            && isset($sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP])
+            && $validatorData[self::VALIDATOR_PASSWORD_CREATE_TIMESTAMP]
+            > $sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP] - $this->getCookie()->getLifetime()
+        ) {
+            return false;
+        }
```

I had to apply at the last part the **invalid_session_fix-2018-03-14-05-10-19.patch** below which is found in https://magento.com/tech-resources/download under **SUPEE-10570** > **invalid_session_fix.patch (0 MB)**

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
index 59b3ea8..35155f1 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
@@ -485,7 +485,7 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
             && isset($validatorData[self::VALIDATOR_PASSWORD_CREATE_TIMESTAMP])
             && isset($sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP])
             && $validatorData[self::VALIDATOR_PASSWORD_CREATE_TIMESTAMP]
-            > $sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP] - $this->getCookie()->getLifetime()
+            > $sessionData[self::VALIDATOR_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP]
         ) {
             return false;
         }
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I am using Magento CE ver. 1.9.3.1, if you found a resolution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an issue with quite a few customers where they call us that they are unable to login and view their account.

The email and password are correct - no login error message, page just reloads to the home page or login page, they can't seem to get into their account!
This happened after applying the patch 10888, and we do have 10752 applied.

After digging I found in table `customer_entity`, and it sparked to me that the affected customers have a timestamp of `created_date` AFTER the `updated_date`. I think it shouldn't be that way right?

So to test, I changed the created_date to be BEFORE the updated_date, even by one minute. For some users this alone helped them to get back into their accounts. While for other users I also had to update their password via SQL, using query:

```
update customer_entity_varchar set value = md5('123456') 
   where where entity_id = 105 /*enter customer's entity_id found in customer_entity */
   and attribute_id in 
      (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'password_hash' 
        and entity_type_id = 1);
```

I haven't got to fully investigate the changes SUPEE 10888 does to customer core files, but there are definitely issues with the patch.

Furthermore, I can't seem to update the customers password via admin panel as I normally would, when saving, the page results in an error.

Using 1.9.2.4

Comment: i have the same issue , did you found any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 1.9.3.7 . Os is ubuntu. PHP version is 7.0.

When tried to applied path SUPPER-10888 getting below error.

```
Checking if a patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
```

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 676 (offset -20 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 57.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 80 (offset -12 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 115 with fuzz 2 (offset -12 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 139 with fuzz 1 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 161 (offset -21 lines).
1 out of 6 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1020 (offset -11 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 151 with fuzz 1 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 731 with fuzz 1 (offset -3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 332 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 755 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 810 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 871.
Hunk #4 succeeded at 883 (offset -2 lines).
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.5.1.2-1.6.2.0.5.1.3.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php
can't find file to patch at input line 600
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

### The text leading up to this was:

|diff --git app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
|index 586c0fe20a0..d6fa2dac0ec 100644
|--- app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php

### |+++ app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php

File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 209.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
checking file app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg

Any idea what is missing?